# SWT java browser backspace key stops working

Tags: java, swt

I open a web page in my java program's swt browser.

Sometimes the backspace key stops working.

has anyone heard of this or know what may fix it?

When i click a button on my swt form the backspace key inside of the browser starts working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in java.  They fixed it in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Bug 110916 – Backspace stops working (due to mouse stuck down)

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=110916

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this may be an SWT issue related to [this bug I filed last week](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321167). If this occurs on Windows, and does not happen inside an IE8 instance with the same webpage, consider adding a comment that report describing your problem.